# How easy is Lua with Qt, compared to QtScript?

Tags: c++, qt, lua, qtscript

I'm just starting C++ development using Qt. However, I'm also interested in using Lua to script my app, given various articles stating its development speed (ease) for writing the workflow/ui/glue of an application. However, out of the box Qt doesn't support it, instead it includes QtScript.

My question is basically should I attempt to use Lua with Qt to develop a commercial app, or stick with QtScript available in the SDK? Primarily a development speed vs. stability question I guess.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've encountered the same dilemma. I much prefer Lua to [ECMAScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) for these sorts of tasks. However, as easy as it is to write Lua bindings, the level of integration provided by [QtScript](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtscript.html) yields a lot of capability out of the box. This includes bindings to built-in [QObject](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qscriptengine.html#newQObject)-derived classes as well as your own classes that inherit from QObject and/or [QScriptClass](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qscriptclass.html).

So, if you only want to script or configure your own classes independent from Qt functionality, then I'd go with Lua. However, if you primarily want to interact with QObject-based types, then QtScript will greatly decrease your initial development time.

The best of both worlds would be the option to parse Lua scripts with an alternate [QScriptEngine](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qscriptengine.html) implementation. I've been meaning to look into how difficult that would be to integrate for some time...

**UPDATE**: [QtLua](http://www.nongnu.org/libqtlua/) is still actively maintained and might solve your problem directly.

Comment: despite the answer is old, it is worth to mention, that using QScript even in a commercial means, the code should comply LGPL. So either the complete code should be OS or at least the part using QScript (e.g. implemented as a lib).

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is so well integrated right now, if you want to integrate lua you will probably have a much higher upfront effort. Also the current implementation (4.6) uses the webkit javascript engine, which means it is blazingly fast.

I have used Javascript and Qt for a current project and it was pretty easy to transport data either way (Qt to Javascript, and the reverse)